# How to acquire full and real bash environment invoking Nodejs child_process exec method

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, child-process

I am writing a [git hook project](https://git.oschina.net/run27017/git-hook) in nodejs, and it will receive a post request from github and execute some command in local machine as specified user. I run the command through node's spawn method in *child_process* module. The main issue is that it cannot set a full and clean environment I want just like loginning through bash. For example, the 'HOME' environment variable isn't set to the user's home directory, and some strange environment variable 'SODU_USER' came in. This is just a simplest issue and there are a lot issues due to this I cannot express very clearly.

Thus, wath I want is to acquire a nice bash environment just like *I login through ssh*.

Provided that the command is 'git pull', and the user executing the command is abc. Maybe the following method work:

1. Firstly, write a script startup.sh:

   ```
   # first unset all environment variables
   for i in `env | sed 's/=.*//'` ; do
       unset $i
   done
   # next do some startups
   source /etc/profile
   source /home/abc/.bashrc
   # ... some other files need to be sourced ...
   ```
2. Then, execute the command 'git pull' like below:

   ```
   child_process.spawn('startup.sh && git pull')
   ```

Maybe it can solve my issue but I cannot be sure. However, this method is not elegant and is there some more accurate and elegant style using nodejs?

Comment: Try `sudo`, it will handle all pam, shell problem. But you may still need to manually create  tty, session yourself.